# MAMP + Websharing osx 10.8

Tags: macos, web, mamp, sharing

I have a local webdev Environement with MAMP.
Now to test my projects on Mobile devices, I deploy the projects to my live server and enable websharing so I can Access the web with the ipad.

I already understood that websharing only works when MAMP doesn't have port 80.
But now after testing on the Mobile device. I can't reach my local Projects because websharing seems to override MAMP. Altough I disabled Websharing it still doesn't work. Do I have to kill Websharing in terminal or something so MAMP can kick in again?

thanks for any helot